# Error con select dependiente php ,sqlsrv,jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, sql-server

Quise ejercitar con esta librería sqlsrv ya que con mysqli me funciono sin problema el ejercicio del select dependiente para regiones,provincias y comunas. Mi problema es el siguiente no se como depurar con jquery para poder capturar el error correctamente pero sin embargo supongo que los datos se envian ya me aparece el  creado en la otra pagina de donde se esta renderizando (getProvincia.php)

JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#region").change(function () {
                $("#region option:selected").each(function () {
id_region = $(this).val();
$.post("lib/getProvincia.php", { id_region: id_region }, function(data){
$("#provincia").html(data);
});            
});
});

});
```

getProvincia.php

```
$query= "SELECT     ProvCod, ProvDes, Id_Region FROM  provincia WHERE     
Id_Region = '$id_region' ORDER BY ProvDes";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($con,$query);

$html= "<option value='0'>Seleccionar Provincia</option>";// esta opcion aparece  como option al seleccionar cualquier region

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 $html.= "<option value='".$row['ProvCod']."'>".$row['ProvDes']."</option>";
 }


 echo $html;

 ?>
```

HTML

```
      <form  method="post" >
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="region">Región :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
 <select class="form-control" id="region"  name="region">
 <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
 <?php get_region();?> //este select si le llena correctamente
  </select>
     </div>

<label class="col-sm-3  control-label" for="provincia">Provincia :</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<select class="form-control"  name="provincia" id="provincia">
</select>
    </div>
</div>

</form>


function get_region(){
$con=conectar();
$query_reg = "SELECT     id_Region, Descripcion FROM region";
if($stmt_reg = sqlsrv_query($con,$query_reg)){
  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_reg)){

?> <option value="<?php echo $row['id_region']; ?>" > <?php echo 
$row['Descripcion']; ?> </option> <?php 

  }
}

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrias aclarar cual es tu pregunta?

Si te refieres a como depurar el jQuery, podrias usar `alert` para comprobar tus datos, o mismamente realizar las consultas JS en consola para checkear los elementos a los que estas intentando llegar.

Comment: Ya solucione el error @ntzz gracias a tu consejo pude depurar correctamente y me arrojo un en esta linea:
    $html.= "<option value='".$row['ProvCod']."'>".$row['ProvDes']."</option>"; 

ahora no recuerdo bien el error pero con la depuración pero era un error de sintaxis en un lado estaba una letra con mayúscula y en el otro con minúscula.

Comment: Me alegro, siempre que necesites depurar, ya sea en JS o cualquier otro lenguaje, recuerda comprobar los valores de las variables con las que estas trabajando para controlar el flujo de la información.